# Should I move UI-Related into an extension inside a separate class?

Tags: swift, xcode, model-view-controller

I am new to Swift and I want to know whether I should move UI-related into an extension inside a separate class or not? For example, I want to move some of my UITextfield custom layouts into an extension of UIViewController inside another .swift file and then I can call back those method inside my ViewController.swift whenever I need it, is it a good practice to avoid (Massive ViewController)?

Your suggestions will be highly appreciate, thanks!

Comment: That's really dealer's choice. I am old school in that regard, and I hate those extensions to classes that add subclass functionality. Others love them.

Comment: @zaitsman why you hate it?

Comment: because if all protocols and inheritance is declared in a single file, i can look at it and know that my class confirms to all of these, and if extensions are used, then i need to look at possibly many files to find out where this declaration is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a lot of similar labels, UIViews and textfields throughout my project. To make the code nicer and speed the process up I have added reusable UI elements in a separate Extensions.swift folder. For example:

```
class Textfield: UITextField {
init(placeholder: String, type: UIKeyboardType, returnKey: UIReturnKeyType, capitalization: UITextAutocapitalizationType, align: NSTextAlignment, borderC: UIColor, textC: UIColor) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    self.placeholder = placeholder
    self.keyboardType = type
    self.returnKeyType = returnKey
    self.autocapitalizationType = capitalization
    self.borderStyle = .none
    self.textAlignment = align
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.font = UIFont(name: nexaBold, size: 25)
    self.textColor = textC
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    self.layer.borderColor = borderC.cgColor
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if align == .left {
        let padding = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0))
        self.leftView = padding
        self.leftViewMode = .always
    }
}
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

And anywhere in the project I can use it by:

```
private nameField = TextField("Enter Name:", .default, .done.... etc)
```